# ReloadData em TableView carregando imagem errada Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Eu tenho um tableview dentro da minha ViewController, e faço algumas ações em cada célula como expandir e excluir.

Quando eu faço a exclusão eu dou um reload na tabela carregando os dados de um json remoto, ele procede com a exclusão normalmente porém a célula que passa a fica na posição da que foi excluída já aparece como se ela estivesse aberta sem que eu tenha clicado nela para abrir.

E antes de dar o reload eu estou usando o seguinte comando

> self.tableList.removeAllObjects() 
>   self.TableAgendamento.reloadData()

Existe uma maneira de resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando reciclagem de células? Tanto as `UITableView` quanto as `UICollectionView` são meio bugadas com isso. As vezes, quando elas reciclam uma célula da memória, elas não atualizam algum componente direito.

Outra coisa que pode estar ocasionando esse problema: onde você mantém esse estado de "aberto" ou "fechado"? Na própria célula? Se for, também pode ser pela questão da reciclagem de células.

Quando você exclui uma célula, a `UITableView` não dá deinit nela. Ao invés disso, guarda a célula no cache. Quando você pede uma célula nova pra `UITableView` através do método `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, antes de inicializar uma nova, ela olha se tem células no cache e te dá uma célula reciclada, caso haja. A célula reciclada não necessariamente vai estar com os valores redefinidos para os de uma célula recém criada.

Portanto, dentro do método onde você compõe a célula, `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, não esqueça de definir completamente o estado da célula.

Comment: Olá Lucas obrigado, é isso mesmo reciclagem de células. além disso eu estava esquecendo de zerar a lista que armazenava o status da células que forma abertas.